# How to add null termination in socket stream buffer. C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, null, stream

I have successfully created a TCP client/server model with C.
Everything is working perfectly so i don't want this question to be mistaken about how to program a TCP client/server in C.

All i want is to send a NullTerminator (with the size of one byte) Through the stream.

Lets say the client is only sending and the server is receiving.
I got down to the following piece of code but it has some problem (which i am looking some help for)

```
/* client code*/
        strcpy(stringToSend,argv[i]);
        strcat(stringToSend,argv[i+1]);
        strcat(stringToSend,"\\0");  //note that double '\\' refers on escaping the '\'
        strcat(stringToSend,argv[i+2]);
        send(mySocket, stringToSend, strlen(stringToSend), 0);
/* client code*/
```

But having a quick look in the code bellow (and the results of it), it's self explanatory about the issue i am dealing with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf("Null in ASCII is <%d>\n", ((char) 0));
    printf("Size of null is <%ld>\n", sizeof((char)0));

    printf("Size of this \\0 is <%ld>\n", sizeof("\0"));
    return 0;
}
```

Terminal output:

```
bash$>./test
Null in ASCII is <0>
Size of null is <1>
Size of this \0 is <2>
bash$>
```

In a few words, with `strcat(stringToSend,"\\0");` i am simply adding the characters `'\''0'` into the string and nothing more.

I tried using `strcat(stringToSend,(char) 0)` in client side to append the null character (of 1 byte) in the string to send to stream but i encoutered the issue that `strcat` and `strcpy` require a pointer to work and not an INT (which `(char) 0` is and i don't think that would be also a way to solve the problem.

I know that every string is null terminated by itself, and i am not looking for this information. All i am trying is to append on my own will into the stream, this null terminator of one byte at specific points. Are there any other functions to help me do that, that i am unaware of?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the `str*` functions... these library functions have no idea how long the string is... each time you call these functions, they (re)calculate the string length according to the first NUL character in the byte stream... consider using `memcpy`, or your NUL character will be overwritten whenever you combine strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
send(mySocket, stringToSend, strlen(stringToSend), 0);
```

The problem is here. There is already a trailing null in the buffer for this to work, but you aren't sending it. Try this:

```
send(mySocket, stringToSend, strlen(stringToSend)+1, 0);
```

You are also misleading yourself with this:

```
printf("Size of this \\0 is <%ld>\n", sizeof("\0"));
```

which prints `sizeof "\0"`, not `sizeof "\\0"`, which is what you want, and should be 3. This is all irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

Don't escape the \0

```
char *s = "\0";
send(mySocket,s,1,0);
```

Comment: If you try `sizeof("\0");` you will see that is 2 bytes. The null terminator on the other hand is 1 byte. (its the terminal output i have posted in my orig post)

Comment: but because of the '1' parameter in send, only one byte is sent.

Comment: a.k.a the '\' because s points to a string of '\' and '0' chars and not in a null terminator.

Comment: \0 is a valid escape sequence, \\0 escapes the '\' making it a literal "\0": try `printf("%d",s[0]);` it will print '0' or NUL

Comment: Checking the terminal output i have posted above, it is clear that "\0" has the size of two bytes, and `(char) 0` has the size of one byte. 
By using double quotes anyway, someone is referring to a string and not a char, and null terminator has the size of char (or is the ASCII 0)

Comment: I will stick to my original post and provide this: 
http://codepad.org/H0ATKz5f. 
In other words s[0] size is 1 because you are refering to the character '\'

Comment: The character code or ascii code is printed as 0 -- ASCII NUL

Comment: Yes ..but the size is different...Size is needed to be 1 and only one!

Comment: Strings in C are automatically NULL-terminated thus the size is not 2 because of a literal "\0" -- you could make s = "" and then the size would be one instead of two NULL charactets

Comment: Or simply `char c = '\0'; send( s, &c, 1, 0 );`

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
memcpy(your_buffer,your_string,strlen(your_string)+1);/*this copies a 
string with its null terminator,
for the next string if your_buffer has allocated enough
memory space (more than strlen(your_string)+strlen(your_other_string)+2*(NULL terminators) 
then:*/
memcpy(your_buffer+strlen(your_string)+1,your_other_string,strlen(your_other_string)+1);
// now your_buffer contains your 2 strings with their null terminators
send(your_socket, your_buffer, (strlen(your_string)+strlen(your_other_string)+2)*sizeof(char), 0);//You've now sent your two strings with their null terminators to your client
```

Now this: *'\0'* == **1 byte** of zero bits(only if your machine implements the C data types standard which is quite likely to happen but don't count on this).

If the standard is followed,this: "/0" is a pointer to a memory area where some characters reside, to be more specific and if I am not wrong, there sits a byte of zeros followed by a byte of zeros, a "nulled null".

PS1: If you send the server "//0" the way you do, it won't see 1 byte of '/0' which its ASCII hexadecimal equal is 00 but 1 byte of '//' which is 2F, and one of '0' which is 30, so proceed with caution.

PS2: This is my first answer ever, so if I need any corrections, feel free to point them out.

PS3:Don't forget to accept if I covered your question.

Comment: Only if your *C compiler* implements the C datatypes standard, which is *required*.

Comment: I mean the data types a machines compiler implements may be bigger than those required by the standard, that can happen from time to time, not for char but generally speaking, right?

Comment: Plus, you shouldn't downvote my first post :'( . I know what this guy asks as I spotted keywords of a same question at the same timing as my project + his name is greekish, so he is from my university 100% and that question has been already asked by him with probability 50-70% in the class. Plus plus, I think I got him covered.

Comment: Stack Exchange community, doesn't allow members with less than 125 reputation to effect the score of a post. I have 58.
Appreciate the effort though and thanks!